# CSS selector to target silibing depending on silibing number

Tags: css, sass

Given a HTML element with some silibings:

```html
    <div id=parent>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        ...
        <div id=fourthToLast></div>
        <div></div>
        <div id=penultimate></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
```

The *penulimate* and the *fourthToLast* silibing are special:
One or the other - but never both - should be shown at different widths,
depending on media breakpoints and total number of silibings.

In the CSS code I put pseudo code selectors:

```
silibingNrOf(#penultimate) mod x = y
```

Example: If parent has a total of 15 silibings, then silibingNrOf(#penultimate) is 14.
silibingNrOf(#penultimate) mod 3 would equal 2.

I need the correct CSS selector syntax for this problem and can't find out how to do it.

```css
    #fourthToLast, #penultimate { display: none; }

    @media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
        
        if silibingNrOf(#penultimate) mod 2 = 0 {
            #penultimate { width: 25%; display: block; }
        }
        
        @media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
        
            #penultimate { display: none; }
        
            if silibingNrOf(#penultimate) mod 3 = 2 {
                #penultimate { width: 33%; display: block; }
            }

            if silibingNrOf(#penultimate) mod 3 = 0 {
                #fourthToLast { width: 16.666%; display: block; }
            }   
        
       }
    }
```

Comment: Sass is just a preprocessor which has no access to the DOM whatsoever. You will need to use JS for advanced conditions.

Comment: @InSync for the (mod 2) condition, I think I could use `#penultimate:nth-of-type(even)` ,true? Now I need something similar for checking on mod 3.

Comment: This took a while, but I don't have time to really verify it before I *really* need to sleep, but I *think* this is what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/oth4br8u/, but - because of `:has()`, and the complex selector contained - it's not supported by Firefox. Chrome seems happy with it though.

Comment: Interesting. Aside from the need to use `:has()`, using a next-to-last element as a pinpoint for calculating the number of elements (minus 1) is incredibly ingenious.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** you could use `:nth-of-type(3n)` for `silibingNrOf(#penultimate) mod 3 = 0` and `:nth-of-type(3n+2)` for `silibingNrOf(#penultimate) mod 3 = 2`. And obviously `:nth-of-type(even)` or `:nth-of-type(2n)` for `silibingNrOf(#penultimate) mod 2 = 0` as you've already figured out. :nth-child() would also work for this case, and the parameters would be the same. I jumped straight to javascript in my first answer and only thought of this after your comment.

**Previous answer:**
You could do the following in javascript:

```
const parent = document.getElementById("parent");
const parentChildrenCount = parent.childElementCount; 
if(parentChildrenCount % 2 === 1){
    parent.addClass("even"); // silibingNrOf(#penultimate) mod 2 = 0
}
if(parentChildrenCount % 3 === 1){
    parent.addClass("triple"); // silibingNrOf(#penultimate) mod 3 = 0
}
else if(parentChildrenCount % 3 === 0){
    parent.addClass("almost-triple"); // silibingNrOf(#penultimate) mod 3 = 2
}
```

and then use these classes to select the elements in your sass code. Also, penultimate and fourthToLast could be selected using [:nth-last-child pseudoselector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child).

Comment: Thank you, sounds promissing! I'll check that tomorrow and then accept this answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Given the structure from the question and all it's variations with 1 to 7 elements (+ the extra elements 'penultimate' and 'fourthToLast'). The empty elements formerly labeled 'penultimate' and 'fourthToLast' don't need an ID for this.

```html
    <div id=parent1>
        <div></div>
        <div>Content 1</div>
    </div>
    
    <div id=parent2>
        <div></div> 
        <div>Content 1</div>
        <div></div> 
        <div>Content 2</div>
    </div>
    
    <div id=parent3>
        <div>Content 1</div>
        <div></div>
        <div>Content 2</div>
        <div></div>
        <div>Content 3</div>
    </div>
    
    <div id=parent4>
        <div>Content 1</div>
        <div>Content 2</div>
        <div></div>
        <div>Content 3</div>
        <div></div>
        <div>Content 4</div>
    </div>
    
    <div id=parent5>
        <div>Content 1</div>
        <div>Content 2</div>
        <div>Content 3</div>
        <div></div>
        <div>Content 4</div>
        <div></div>
        <div>Content 5</div>
    </div>
    
    <div id=parent6>
        <div>Content 1</div>
        <div>Content 2</div>
        <div>Content 3</div>
        <div>Content 4</div>
        <div></div>
        <div>Content 5</div>
        <div></div>
        <div>Content 6</div>
    </div>
    
    <div id=parent7>
        <div>Content 1</div>
        <div>Content 2</div>
        <div>Content 3</div>
        <div>Content 4</div>
        <div>Content 5</div>
        <div></div>
        <div>Content 6</div>
        <div></div>
        <div>Content 7</div>
    </div>
```

**The task is**

```
Initially hide the two (non-core) extra child elements,       
which will always be the penultimate and the fourth-to-last child.    

if 400px <= screen width < 800px
    if count of core childs is odd
        display the penultimate child at 25% width

if screen width >= 800px
    if count of core childs mod 3 = 2
        display the penultimate child with 16.66% width

    if count of core childs mod 3 = 1
        display the fourth-to-last child with 33.33% width
```

To be solved without javascript and without functions not widely supported by all browsers (:has() / Firefox).

**Solution**:

```scss
:is(#parent1, #parent2, #parent3, #parent4, #parent5, #parent6, #parent7) {

    div:nth-last-child(2) {
        display: none;

        @media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
            &:is(:first-child, :nth-of-type(even)) {
                width: 25%;
                display: block;
            }
            @media screen and (min-width: 800px) {          
                &:nth-of-type(even) {
                    display: none;
                }
                &:is(:first-child, :nth-of-type(3n + 2)) {
                    width: 33.33%;
                    display: block;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    div:nth-last-child(4) {
        display: none;

        @media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
            &:nth-child(3n + 1) {
                width: 16.66%;
                display: block;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Special thanks go to [David Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82548/david-thomas) for his very inspiring [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/oth4br8u/) that put me on track.